# Technique for server receiving chunked data from client

Tags: java, http, server, client

I'm working with a web application that has a javascript front-end and Tomcat/java server. The front-end is simply a table where the user can modify the table and add more rows and fill out the form. I wrote some code so that the user can save the table. It sends the data in the form to the server through an http request, the server writes the data to an oracle database, everything works great.

As the table grows however, it is no longer feasible to send it all in one request. One suggestion was to split the rows up into different requests, but then if one request succeeds and another fails the oracle table will be incorrect.

What is the preferred method to send the server multiple chunks of data while the server does not begin to work on it until all the data has been received? I've seen plenty of SO questions about TCP connections regarding data chunking, but not really around http requests.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to *display* the whole table to the user? This alone doesn't scale. In any practical implementation you will have to provide the user with filters. Then you should certainly only send the changed rows, as per the answers given.

Comment: Good point, however in my case the creation of the table (~50 rows with a few columns of text) required more data to be sent over than the current limit. I should probably incorporate your suggestion, however there's still the issue of what if the client wants more changes than can be expressed in the http request size limit?

Comment: Same answer. Don't give him that opportunity. Only show him as many rows as can be changed at once.

Comment: That's not feasible for my application at all. The table is a list of rules that are used together. I'm not going to get into specifics but there is the possibility that a change would need to be made for all rows and they'd need to be saved as one transactional change. Worst case scenario I could do something like send an http request telling the server how many rows, have the server save that in a file, then save everything to files until number of rows received = rows from the first request. That just seems clunky and like there would probably be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to send the whole table on each request? Just send the difference. I assume that you have ids for the rows or some identifier. Send the list of ids of deleted rows, list of new rows and list of updated rows. That way, you won't have to send all table data.

Comment: Good point, however in my case the creation of the table (~50 rows with a few columns of text) required more data to be sent over than the current limit. I should probably incorporate your suggestion, however there's still the issue of what if the client wants more changes than can be expressed in the http request size limit?

Answer (score 0):

Do you **really** need to send the entire table every time user changes it? Why not simply create an API which allows you to modify just the rows which were modified? It seems its much better solution. This way, the client will send only the relevant data, e.g. the single added/modified row.